# CSV write is starting from the label column

Tags: python, csv

This works fine but the problem is, when it write the first row it writes it adjecent to the column label. The rest is fine.

How can I fix this?

```
row = []

with open('train.json') as json_data:
     d = json.load(json_data)

for each in d:
    sentence = each["text"]
    senti_value = each["sentiment"]

    row.append(sentence)
    row.append(senti_value)

    with open('data.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        writer.writerow(row)

    csvFile.close()

    row = []
```

Output Image:

[image]

In this image at the top right, after sentiment the sentence occur. I have to fix that and bring it to next line.

Comment: Add `csvFile.write('\n')`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey - extra blank rows are being inserted after every sentence. I tried.

Comment: This is an issue `row.append(sentence)`. The writer expects sublist representing rows. `row.append([sentence, senti_value])`. That aside, you shouldn't be opening the file inside a `for` loop

Comment: I didn't understand your first part. what you suggested is not what I want. For the second part do suggest a better way

Comment: It would be cleaner code to open data.csv for ‘w’ once, outside the for loop, and then in the loop add each row - have you tried that

Comment: And using the with statement means you don’t need the .close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to write your column headers *once*, then write the data rows:

```
with open('train.json') as json_data:
     d = json.load(json_data)

column_headers = ['Sentence', 'Senti value']

# Open the csv file outside the loop, so we only open it once.
# We could open in 'w' mode, but 'a' is OK too.
with open('data.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)

    # Write the column headers to the file.
    writer.writerow(column_headers)

    # Write each data row to the file.
    for each in d:
        sentence = each["text"]
        senti_value = each["sentiment"]
        row = []
        row.append(sentence)
        row.append(senti_value)

        writer.writerow(row)
```